# Using a method to return amount of values entered into an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, numbers, return

Okay here's a Java assignment I've been having trouble with. I asked earlier about this and got some good comments and advice, but have since understood the assignment more clearly and the issue has changed a bit. So here's the assignment:

> ...Program should ask for integers (max 100 integers) until the users
>   types in zero. Integers can vary from one to one hundred and they are
>   stored in an array that has 100 elements. Numbers are asked for with
>   the askInfo method, which receives the array with numbers as
>   parameter. Method returns the number of integers. The number zero is
>   not saved in the array; it is merely used to stop giving input...

Program to complete:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RevisionExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] tempArray = new int[100];
        System.out.println("Type in numbers. Type zero to quit.");

        int amountOfNumbers = askInfo(tempArray);
        int[] realArray = new int[amountOfNumbers];
        copyInfo(realArray, tempArray);
        setArray(realArray);
        printArray(realArray);
    }


    // Your code here
    public static void printArray(int[] realArray ) {

        System.out.println("\Ordered array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < realArray .length; i++) {
            System.out.println(realArray [i]);

        }
    }
```

Example print:

> Type in numbers. Type zero to quit.
>   1. number: 3
>   2. number: 8
>   3. number: 5
>   4. number: 6
>   5. number: 9
>   6. number: 0
>
> Ordered array:  9 8 6 5 3

I'm struggling with the askInfo method. So far I've written this but it returns only zeroes. Here's my askInfo method:

```
public static int askInfo(int[] tempArray) {   //askinfo-metodi

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((i+1) + ". number: ");
        tempArray[i] = reader.nextInt();
        if (tempArray[i] == 0) {
            return tempArray[i];    
        }
    }
    return tempArray[i];
}
```

How can I make it to register the input and get the amount of numbers to be passed to the next method in the assignment as described in the assignment.

Comment: Do not post the whole assignment and all your code - show us only what you have a problem with, what have you tried, what is your output vs. expected output, if there are any errors etc.

Comment: What do you want askInfo() to do? Return an array of numbers? Return how many numbers it contains?

Comment: If I understand you, you want this method to return the size of the array, in which case you should be returning `i`, not `tempArray[i]`

Comment: @ParisNelson: It's declared outside of the loop

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks for the correction @AndrewMartin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Numbers are asked for with the askInfo method, which receives the array with numbers as parameter. Method returns the number of integers."

Look at your current askInfo() method. You are returning element i of your array. You want to return the total size of your array, not one individual element. How could you do that?

*Hint: Look at what you are returning and remember that Java numbering starts at 0, not 1.*

P.S. In future, only post what is *necessary* to solve your problem. There's a lot of code here that isn't needed to solve your issue.